# Magento 2.2.4 Web Setup Wizard 'This page isn't working'

Tags: setup, http-error-500, web-setup-wizard, magento2.2.4

I have freshly installed Magento 2.2.4 through softaculous installer in cPanel. 
After finish installing, **Admin > System Web Setup Wizard not working**. The link redirects me to **..../setup** and it shows '**This page isn't working ....com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500**'. Please check screenshot.

[image: Web Setup Wizard redirects to this]

Anyone has a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. I am installing Magento 2.3.1 with Sample data. After changing the php version to 7.1 has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use MAMP install magento2, have the same issue. I think it is a version issue, please check MAMP 4.5 (php 7.1.12) and magento 2.2.7. it works on me, before that, please use the MAMP's php rather than mac's PHP.
How to set MAMP'PHP : https://cloudkul.com/blog/magento2-installation-mac-os/

Answer (score -1):

Please Check Error Log file generated in this location:-

> /var/log/httpd/ -> centos, archlinux ...
>
> /var/log/apache2/ -> debian, ubuntu ...
>
> /var/log/nginx/ -> nginx server ...